# Is the best_estimator_ returned by RandomizedSearchCV already trained in all data?

Tags: scikit-learn

When you run rs = RandomizedSearchCV.fit(...), you can get the best estimator found at rs.best_estimator_.

My question is: Is that estimator already trained with the whole dataset? Or is it one of the estimators trained during the cross validation and therefore it was not trained with all data because some data was left to make the evaluation?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It does not say so, so probably not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it retrains the best model on the whole dataset. You can control this behaviour with the boolean `refit` parameter (`True` by default).